# VBA Offset Loop

Tags: vba, excel

I am fairly new to VBA and am working on a summary for our Employee clockings. 
I have the employees information in a reports formatted below [image 1]
but would like to set a button to export these to an annual table (in another work sheet) in the format seen in [image 2] once payroll has been compiled at the end of a month.

What each employee report looks like: (i want all the cells in green)

[image]

The list of reports seen above - the same layout for around 55+ employees this list continues downwards with an offset of 42.

[image]

How I want to format the data taken from each employee :

[image]

Currently I have my code written (see below) which works for the first employee, but I need to copy the same selection of cells with an offset of 42 cells down, approximately 55 times, while offsetting the annual summary page down by one to move to a new line.
I appreciate my code is probably very messy so if there any any improvements to this I can make that would help too!

```
Sub AnnualSummaryTest()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'------------Set Variables----------
Dim EmployeeName            As Range
Dim Month                   As Range
Dim ClockNumber             As Range
Dim ShiftHours              As Range
Dim PayPeriodStart          As Range
Dim PayPerdiodEnd           As Range
'-----------------------------------
Dim TotalHours              As Range
Dim TotalWorkedHours        As Range
Dim CountHolidays           As Range
Dim TotalSickHours          As Range
Dim TotalSaturdayHours      As Range
Dim TotalBankHolidayHours   As Range
Dim CountSSPDays            As Range
Dim CountFlexiDays          As Range
'-----------------------------------
Dim PasteRange              As Range
'-----------------------------------

'------------Set Ranges-------------
Set EmployeeName = Worksheets("Monthly Summary").Range("J4")
Set Month = Worksheets("Monthly Summary").Range("J5")
Set ClockNumber = Worksheets("Monthly Summary").Range("O4")
Set ShiftHours = Worksheets("Monthly Summary").Range("O5")
Set PayPeriodStart = Worksheets("Monthly Summary").Range("T4")
Set PayPerdiodEnd = Worksheets("Monthly Summary").Range("T5")
'-----------------------------------
Set TotalHours = Worksheets("Monthly Summary").Range("K41")
Set TotalWorkedHours = Worksheets("Monthly Summary").Range("K42")
Set CountHolidays = Worksheets("Monthly Summary").Range("K43")
Set TotalSickHours = Worksheets("Monthly Summary").Range("Q41")
Set TotalSaturdayHours = Worksheets("Monthly Summary").Range("Q42")
Set TotalBankHolidayHours = Worksheets("Monthly Summary").Range("Q43")
Set CountSSPDays = Worksheets("Monthly Summary").Range("T41")
Set CountFlexiDays = Worksheets("Monthly Summary").Range("T42")
'-----------------------------------
Set PasteRange = Worksheets("Annual").Range("A2")
'-----------------------------------

'------------Copy Ranges------------
EmployeeName.Copy
    With PasteRange.Offset(0, 0)
    .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
    SkipBlanks = False
    End With
Month.Copy
    With PasteRange.Offset(0, 1)
    .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
    SkipBlanks = False
    End With
ClockNumber.Copy
    With PasteRange.Offset(0, 2)
    .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
    SkipBlanks = False
    End With
ShiftHours.Copy
    With PasteRange.Offset(0, 3)
    .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
    SkipBlanks = False
    End With
PayPeriodStart.Copy
    With PasteRange.Offset(0, 4)
    .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
    SkipBlanks = False
    End With
PayPerdiodEnd.Copy
    With PasteRange.Offset(0, 5)
    .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
    SkipBlanks = False
    End With
'-----------------------------------
TotalHours.Copy
    With PasteRange.Offset(0, 6)
    .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
    SkipBlanks = False
    End With
TotalWorkedHours.Copy
    With PasteRange.Offset(0, 7)
    .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
    SkipBlanks = False
    End With
CountHolidays.Copy
    With PasteRange.Offset(0, 8)
    .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
    SkipBlanks = False
    End With
TotalSickHours.Copy
    With PasteRange.Offset(0, 9)
    .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
    SkipBlanks = False
    End With
TotalSaturdayHours.Copy
    With PasteRange.Offset(0, 10)
    .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
    SkipBlanks = False
    End With
TotalBankHolidayHours.Copy
    With PasteRange.Offset(0, 11)
    .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
    SkipBlanks = False
    End With
CountSSPDays.Copy
    With PasteRange.Offset(0, 12)
    .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
    SkipBlanks = False
    End With
CountFlexiDays.Copy
    With PasteRange.Offset(0, 13)
    .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
    SkipBlanks = False
    End With
'-----------------------------------


Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
MsgBox "Export Complete"

End Sub
```

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just loop and use a counter: (general idea, I can't give you a better solution if I can't see how the employee's data is organized)

```
emp_offset = 42
for i = 0 to n ' n = 55??
    EmployeeName.offset(i,0).Copy
    With PasteRange.Offset(i, 0)
      .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
       SkipBlanks = False
    End With
    Month.offset(emp_offset*i,0).Copy
    With PasteRange.Offset(i, 1)
      .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
      SkipBlanks = False
    End With
next
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer; please see added pictures to hopefully give you a better idea.

Comment: I changed the Paste Range formula to move one line in each iteration. This should work. Then only thing is that the number of employees can't be determined in your current layout. If you had a list of employees then then size of the range would be the value of 'n'

Comment: thank you, I have a list of employees in another Table if that helps? the table name is 'Number_Name_Lookup' which would give a list of employees included in the report. with regards to your code how do i go about pasting each individual variable i need repeatedly? thanks

Comment: I updated  my answer, just put everything inside the loop :)

Comment: I just ran your loop quickly and it populates the names great. however it seems to be missing every other name. ie it is giving me `name1 | name3 | name5` rather than `name 1|name2|name3|name4|name5`

Comment: Adjust the offset. I set it to 42 since you mentioned that the data is 42 rows apart. If it is skipping some names then the offset is too large and is skipping them, I presume

Comment: I think it is to do with the pasting offset? i changed the offset to 21 and it still did the same thing.

Comment: can you send me your workbook? it's waaaay easier (gerardo.flores87 at gmail)

Comment: Thank you, i have sent a quick email :)

Comment: There's nothing in my inbox, are you sure you sent it?

Comment: Resent - it bounced back as unsafe attachments - sent via wetransfer instead

Comment: I just saw my mistake. Remove the i = i+1 at then end, that should fix it :)

Comment: Perfect! that has fixed the missing alternates out - I now need it to offset and loop the rest of the columns on that table- many thanks!

Comment: Figured it out - `With PasteRange.Offset(emp_offset * i, 1)` needs to be `With PasteRange.Offset(i, 1)` :) thank you again this is great!

Comment: @DeanCohen Instead of inserting the answer into original question, you should put your answer as answer to your own question.

Comment: Solution inserted as new answer - Apologies

Answer (score 0):

My Solution here, With thanks to Gerardo Flores.

```
Sub AnnualSummaryTest()

'disables screen flickering
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'Amount of cells to offset downwards
CopyOffset = 42

'------------Set Variables----------
Dim EmployeeName            As Range
Dim Month                   As Range
Dim ClockNumber             As Range
Dim ShiftHours              As Range
Dim PayPeriodStart          As Range
Dim PayPerdiodEnd           As Range
'-----------------------------------
Dim TotalHours              As Range
Dim TotalWorkedHours        As Range
Dim CountHolidays           As Range
Dim TotalSickHours          As Range
Dim TotalSaturdayHours      As Range
Dim TotalBankHolidayHours   As Range
Dim CountSSPDays            As Range
Dim CountFlexiDays          As Range
'-----------------------------------
Dim PasteRange              As Range
'-----------------------------------

'------------Set Ranges-------------
Set EmployeeName = Worksheets("Monthly Summary").Range("J4")
Set Month = Worksheets("Monthly Summary").Range("J5")
Set ClockNumber = Worksheets("Monthly Summary").Range("O4")
Set ShiftHours = Worksheets("Monthly Summary").Range("O5")
Set PayPeriodStart = Worksheets("Monthly Summary").Range("T4")
Set PayPerdiodEnd = Worksheets("Monthly Summary").Range("T5")
'-----------------------------------
Set TotalHours = Worksheets("Monthly Summary").Range("K41")
Set TotalWorkedHours = Worksheets("Monthly Summary").Range("K42")
Set CountHolidays = Worksheets("Monthly Summary").Range("K43")
Set TotalSickHours = Worksheets("Monthly Summary").Range("Q41")
Set TotalSaturdayHours = Worksheets("Monthly Summary").Range("Q42")
Set TotalBankHolidayHours = Worksheets("Monthly Summary").Range("Q43")
Set CountSSPDays = Worksheets("Monthly Summary").Range("T41")
Set CountFlexiDays = Worksheets("Monthly Summary").Range("T42")
'-----------------------------------
Set PasteRange = Worksheets("Annual").Range("A2")
'-----------------------------------

'------------Copy Ranges------------
'Loop Start
'n is number of times to run offset
n = 55
For i = 0 To n
'-----------------------------------
    EmployeeName.Offset(CopyOffset * i, 0).Copy
    With PasteRange.Offset(i, 0)
      .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
       SkipBlanks = False
    End With

    Month.Offset(CopyOffset * i, 0).Copy
    With PasteRange.Offset(i, 1)
      .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
      SkipBlanks = False
    End With

    ClockNumber.Offset(CopyOffset * i, 0).Copy
    With PasteRange.Offset(i, 2)
      .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
      SkipBlanks = False
    End With

    ShiftHours.Offset(CopyOffset * i, 0).Copy
    With PasteRange.Offset(i, 3)
      .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
      SkipBlanks = False
    End With

    PayPeriodStart.Offset(CopyOffset * i, 0).Copy
    With PasteRange.Offset(i, 4)
      .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
       SkipBlanks = False
    End With

    PayPerdiodEnd.Offset(CopyOffset * i, 0).Copy
    With PasteRange.Offset(i, 5)
      .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
      SkipBlanks = False
    End With
'-----------------------------------
    TotalHours.Offset(CopyOffset * i, 0).Copy
    With PasteRange.Offset(i, 6)
      .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
      SkipBlanks = False
    End With

    TotalWorkedHours.Offset(CopyOffset * i, 0).Copy
    With PasteRange.Offset(i, 7)
      .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
      SkipBlanks = False
    End With

    CountHolidays.Offset(CopyOffset * i, 0).Copy
    With PasteRange.Offset(i, 8)
      .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
       SkipBlanks = False
    End With

    TotalSickHours.Offset(CopyOffset * i, 0).Copy
    With PasteRange.Offset(i, 9)
      .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
      SkipBlanks = False
    End With

    TotalSaturdayHours.Offset(CopyOffset * i, 0).Copy
    With PasteRange.Offset(i, 10)
      .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
      SkipBlanks = False
    End With

    TotalBankHolidayHours.Offset(CopyOffset * i, 0).Copy
    With PasteRange.Offset(i, 11)
      .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
      SkipBlanks = False
    End With

    CountSSPDays.Offset(CopyOffset * i, 0).Copy
    With PasteRange.Offset(i, 12)
      .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
       SkipBlanks = False
    End With

    CountFlexiDays.Offset(CopyOffset * i, 0).Copy
    With PasteRange.Offset(i, 13)
      .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
      SkipBlanks = False
    End With
'-----------------------------------
    Next


'-----------------------------------
'Removes 'walking ants' on copied selection
Application.CutCopyMode = False
'Resets Screenupdating to true
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
'Pop up box on completion
MsgBox "      Export Complete      "

End Sub
```